# CouchDB view curl returns javascript db

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have some documents in a database sitting in a couchdb server. I'm struggling to create a view that works. The documents are formatted as such:

```
{
  "_id": "2018_1_17",
  "_rev": "2-d6b8e691925e9bae697c2df054eb77f0",

  "name1.com": {
    "Title": "string",
    "Date": "Thu, 11 Jan 2018 08:55:21 +0000",
    "Site": "string",
    "Description": "string"
  },
  "name2.com": {
    "Title": "title",
    "Date": "Thu, 11 Jan 2018 06:20:43 +0000",
    "Site": "string",
    "Description": "string"
  },
...
```

I've tried a couple of views, for example:

```
function (doc) {

      if(doc.Title && doc.Date) {
        emit(doc.Title, doc.Date);
    }
}
```

etc.

When I do a curl though, it returns the javascript code of the view and no actual results.
I would guess my map function is just wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include your curl operation?

Comment: Joshua - could you share the CURL statement you used and the complete source of the design document defining the view please?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your `curl` command and I don't know why it is not working, but there is something else which doesn't look right:

In your view function your using `doc.Title` and `doc.Date`, however, in your document, there is not a `doc.Title` field and there is not a `doc.Date` field, since `Title` and `Date` are sub-fields inside `name1.com` and `name2.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not getting back sooner. It seems my curl command wasn't quite right.

It was:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/rss_feeds/_design/_by_date/
```

It needs to be:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/rss_feeds/_design/_by_date/_view/_by_date
```